# I m trying to draw radar graph using matplotlib in python, but i want to know how we can show values of data on radar graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

How can we show values on a radar graph which helps to better compare different attributes?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
categories = ['ANN1', 'ANN2', 'ANN3', 'ANN4', 'ANN5', 'ANN6']
categories = [*categories, categories[0]]
RMSE_train = [40, 40, 50, 40, 30,60]
RMSE_vald = [50, 50, 40, 50, 20,50]
RMSE_test = [30, 40, 50, 30, 50,40]
RMSE_train = [*RMSE_train,RMSE_train[0]]
RMSE_vald = [*RMSE_vald, RMSE_vald[0]]
RMSE_test = [*RMSE_test, RMSE_test[0]]

label_loc = np.linspace(start=0, stop=2 * np.pi, num=len(RMSE_train))

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.subplot(polar=True)
plt.plot(label_loc, RMSE_train, label='RMSE train')
plt.plot(label_loc, RMSE_vald, label='RMSE vald')
plt.plot(label_loc, RMSE_test, label='RMSE test')
plt.title('ANN model comparison', size=20, y=1.05)
lines, labels = plt.thetagrids(np.degrees(label_loc), labels=categories)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't understand this question. What aspect of the output would you like to change and how?

Comment: as i draw radar graph. after that i want to show those particular values of attributes or parameter which i have used to draw radar graph for more clarification. let suppose i have four model for one parameter with value 4,5,6,8. i want to show these values on radar graph